# Laravel 5.2: Data passed to the view not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, centos6

So there is a really weird thing happening in this Laravel project I'm working on.
Im passing an array with data to my blade view but when in the view the variable shows as empty!

This only happens on the live server, on my local homestead vagrant box everything works no problem. I have no idea why that is happening and can't seem to figure out.

My Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->view_data["representatives"] = array("Bruno", "Test", "Hey");
    return view("account.index")->with($this->view_data);
}
```

My Blade View:

```
@forelse($representatives as $representative)
    <p>{{ $representative }}</p>
@empty
    <p>There are no users yet!</p>
@endforelse
```

Even if I do

```
print_r($representatives)
```

It shows as empty, when locally I get the array correctly.

So like I said, the weird thing is that locally, that works just fine with the for each working no problem and printing the names.

When on the server, it does not work.

The interesting thing is that when dumping the contents of the variable **$representatives** locally I get the array no problem but on the server it shows as if the array was **empty**.

Is not even that the variable can't be found. It is like if the contents of the variable got erased completely.

Any ideas? I've been on this the entire morning and so far no luck.
Thanks again!

Comment: Might not fix it but would be more readable if you said `$representatives as $representative` then output `$representative`

Comment: Yeah! That was a copy and paste failure of mine. Forget about the forelse, if I do a print_r($representatives) it shows as empty.

Comment: Try `dd()` the session to see what you have passed to the view. Maybe there's a typo or something.

Comment: `dd(session()->all())` should do the trick

Comment: Are you sure you have exact same code as you showed above and you haven't had earlier anything else in this file and you put this only for testing? Please make sure you are using up-to-date view. Use `php artisan view:clear` to clear current views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
@forelse($representatives as $representative)
    <p>{{ $representative }}</p>
@empty
    <p>There are no users yet!</p>
@endforelse
```

OR

Try this

```
public function index()
{
    $this->view_data["representatives"] = array("Bruno", "Test", "Hey");
    return view("account.index")->with("representatives",$this->view_data);
}
```

OR

Try this

```
public function index()
{
    $this->view_data["representatives"] = array("Bruno", "Test", "Hey");
    return view("account.index",$this->view_data);
}
```

Comment: How is this different?

Comment: You used the same variable in the before and after as in forelse loop.

Comment: PHP will iterate over a copy of the array so overwriting the original one while iterating doesn't matter. Unless this is a version difference thing.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was my copy and paste being terrible. I have it like that already. Like I said, is not a syntax problem. Is a problem when sending the variable to the blade view. Forget about the forelse, if I do a print_r($representatives) it shows as empty.

Comment: Still didn't work! I have no idea why this is happening